# Can puppet install the Apache2 package on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, puppet

Various documents on the Internet indicate that it is normal to use puppet to ensure that the Apache2 package is installed in Ubuntu eg

```
   package { 'apache2':
      ensure => present,
    }
    service { 'apache2':
      ensure => running,
      enable => true,
      require => Package['apache2']
    }
```

However, when testing this recently with Ubuntu Trusty, my agent is showing the following error:

```
Could not evaluate: Could not find init script or upstart conf file for 'apache2'
```

When I use the puppetlabs Apache module, I can install Apache from scratch on Trusty, but this seems to be actioned by applying static files from the module rather than by actioning a standard apt-get package installation.

Also, if I pre-install Apache2 with

```
apt-get install apache2
```

The standard puppet module code above works.

It seems that at this point you can't use Puppet to install Apache2 from a vanilla Ubuntu Trusty installation.

The same issue is reported here for Debian 7
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758036/install-apache-module-with-puppet-on-debian-7

Comment: I did test using ubuntu 14:10 container and I didn't find any problem, please provide puppet apply name_of_the_file.pp --debug

Comment: Today, I ran the same test and it appear to be working. I am working in Amazon EC2 here, and deployed a new Ubuntu Trusty instance. I was working with scratch instances yesterday to, just deploying them, installing the puppet client and killing them again.